# php - sprintf very simple question

Tags: php

I'm just wondering if omitting an argument from sprintf is going to cause any issues.

I can't recall for sure, but I think on one of my sites if I omitted the arguments it error'd out, but I tried it on a different server and it's not posting any issues with all php error notices turned on.

Just want to double check!

Example:

```
sprintf('This is an example %s','test'); // outputs "This is an example test"
sprintf('This is an example','test'); // outputs "This is an example"
```

Comment: It'd be a waste of cpu cycles, as sprintf would still parse the string looking for format codes, but it wouldn't be an error. Not providing values for all the format characters, on the other hand, would be an error. `sprintf('This is a %d decimal');` would fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will error if you pass too few arguments, but too many is fine.  Just like the rest of PHP, if you pass too many arguments, they will just be ignored.

```
$ php -r "echo sprintf('foo %s');"
PHP Warning:  printf(): Too few arguments in Command line code on line 1
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() Command line code:0
PHP   2. printf() Command line code:1

Warning: printf(): Too few arguments in Command line code on line 1

Call Stack:
    0.0005     314336   1. {main}() Command line code:0
    0.0006     314408   2. printf() Command line code:1

$ php -r "printf('foo %s', 'foo', 'bar');"
foo foo
```

Comment: awesome, couldn't remember what the error was I had before but too few arguments sounds like what it was. This solves my problem, thanks!